# Installing Couchbase on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL 2

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install `couchbase-server-community` on my Ubuntu 18.04 WSL 2 using the basic instructions from the Couchbase official website.

When running `sudo apt install couchbase-server-community`, I receive however

```
Unpacking couchbase-server-community (6.6.0-7909-1) ...
Setting up couchbase-server-community (6.6.0-7909-1) ...
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
dpkg: error processing package couchbase-server-community (--configure):
 installed couchbase-server-community package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 couchbase-server-community
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I install and run the latest Couchbase for my Ubuntu version succesfully?

Comment: It appears that this package assumes `systemd` for its setup. WSL doesn't have `systemd`. This is the problem you need to solve. You could try to [disable postinstall scripts](https://serverfault.com/questions/347937/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-all-post-install-configuration-steps) and manually go through the postinstallation steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @berndbausch mentioned in the comments, WSL does not support `systemd` at this time, and the couchbase package is definitely trying to use `systemd`.

In addition to @berndbausch's recommendation to try disabling the postinstall scripts, here are two other possibilities.  Please note that I have not done either of these myself, but at least the first should be completely workable.

First, and probably easiest, would be to install Docker on your WSL2 Ubuntu distribution and use [the Couchbase docker image](https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/quick-start/quickstart-docker-image-manual-cb65.html).

Second, Couchbase also provides a ["non-package-based" installation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/non-root.html) method.  For potential future readers, this has been confirmed as working in WSL in the comments by @Avi, who asked the original question.  However, it appears that setting the ulimit (as documented in the non-package-based install) currently requires a workaround in WSL.  Before setting the ulimit, run `su $USER`.  Note that raising the ulimit will only be valid in that subshell.  See [this Github comment and thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1688#issuecomment-605536435) for more information.

Comment: Using the "non-package-based" installation worked, however I had to tinker a bit with it, since setting the ulimit up for my user means I also have to use this fix here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1688 Just wanted to provide all details so that answer seeking people would have the whole story :)

Comment: Good to hear this worked!  I'd love to edit the ulimit info into the answer, but I see *multiple* workarounds suggested on the issue you linked to.  Which one worked for you specifically?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry! I should have been more specific: What worked for me is https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1688#issuecomment-605536435, which is basically logging in with your user (from your user as well, funny enough) aka `su username` :)